# My ubuntu freezes when I switch workspaces with a full screen video playing

Tags: video, workspaces

One cool thing about my mac is I can switch workspaces while having a full screen YouTube video running. On my Ubuntu machine it causes the video to freeze. Sometimes it works (with a little flickering). But if I do it a few times the video will return but be completely frozen. I am unable to recover and I'll have to power off the computer. However, I can still hear the audio when this happens. Perhaps my hardware is a little too old or slow? Or maybe it's just a driver issue. Wondering if anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: No, I just don't use multiple workspaces.

Comment: Well, if it helps at all I managed to solve the problem by using an older NVIDIA driver.